# haproxy for routing to specific web servers

Tags: proxy, nat, haproxy, access-control-list, web

I have a haproxy server with two nics running ip addresses 192.168.1.99(connected to router) and 192.168.2.1(to a switch connected with web servers). The haproxy is nat-ed also. We have two servers namely web1.xyz.com and web2.xyz.com running sentora control panel which will be used to host several websites according to our clients requirements.

Here is what is am trying to achieve.... I want to access the control panels using their designated host address(web1.xyz.com, web2.xyz.com) and access the websites in those servers at the same time. Customers might add new domains on their own which should also be served automatically.

We have tried haproxy to acheive this but am able to only access the control panels but not the websites. To access the websites, i have to manually furnish the hdr using acl in haproxy configuration which is much painful.

Can somebody advise me something like an automated solution or a simpler one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use haproxy admin socket and script it. Look over [documentation](http://haproxy.tech-notes.net/9-2-unix-socket-commands/) and find if this fill your requirements. Unfornutatelly, AFAIK HAProxy cannot save configuration modifited thru socket into file so changes are lost when haproxy is restarted. Hint: modify running config thru socket and haproxy.cfg file.

Comment: I will give it a try and see how it works. Cheers!